# Google Analytics with asynchronous Calls to two different accounts

Tags: ajax, flash, actionscript-3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a flash site that calls a JavaScript function to track events inside of the application, the _gaq is already implemented in the  section of the html and it works perfectly fine with one account:

```
function customTracker(clickEventName) 
{  
    _gaq.push (["_trackPageview", clickEventName]); 
}
```

but now my customer wants to include special events from 3rd party companies and needs these to track into a different GA account. Before I try this out on the live server I wanted to ask if this would work:

```
function customTracker(clickEventName) 
{  
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"]); // the regular account
    _gaq.push (["_trackPageview", clickEventName]); 
}

function customThirdPartyTracker(clickEventName) 
{  
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"]); // the new account for third party tracking
    _gaq.push (["_trackPageview", clickEventName]); 
}
```

I found similar questions on StackOverflow but the answer was only 'to use the new asynchronous tracking' but no word on how to really implement it.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I tried it after Ewan checked it and yes, it is working now!

Comment: Upvote because your sample code of using async GA is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem sending data to multiple GA accounts so your code should work.